# How to preserve formulas made in a macro on the worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have the next code in VBA:

```
Do While ZSDCM.Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
  ZSDCM.Cells(i, 60).Value = Application.IfError(Application.Index(z16, Application.Match(ZSDCM.Cells(i, 35).Value, SalesOrder, False), 1), "")
 i = i + 1
Loop
```

But after running this sub, cells affected only show the value not the formula and i would like my formulas were visible in the correspondign cell once my macro has been executed.

Comment: `ZSDCM.Cells(i, 60).Value.offset(0,1).Value = "'=IfError(Index(Z16,match(AI"& i & ",SalesOrder,False),1),"""")"` I think. Basically, what you have is the `VBA` formula, and you just need to translate that into a regular Excel formula and put that in the cell next to it. I'm not sure my example is exactly correct, but hopefully you can see what I'm getting at.

Comment: Also if you want the *formula* to be in the cell (rather than the text of the formula as a string), you could modify the idea of @BruceWayne by using `ZSDCM.Cells(i, 60).Formula` (with corresponding tweaks to the right hand side) rather than `ZSDCM.Cells(i, 60).Value.offset(0,1).Value`